# Docusign - PHP - Client set expiration days using Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, docusignapi

I have been implementing Docusign in my web application using Symfony. I want to add expire days for Docusign document while creating envelops. 
This is what I've tried:

```
$expirations = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Expirations([
        'expire_after' => "1", 'expire_enabled' => true, 'expire_warn' => "0"]);
$envelope_definition->setNotification($expirations);
```

But this not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to the admin for this account (https://admindemo.docusign.com/reminders-expirations) and check the box that says "Allow senders to override account defaults".
Otherwise, the defaults in there would be set even if you try to override them.

(the URL above is our Developer Sandbox, remove the "demo" part for production)